# Spring boot CRUD JDBC API unable to connect to Oracle Database

Tags: spring, database, oracle, spring-boot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a CRUD JDBC API that will be able to being able to GET, POST, UPDATE, and DELETE data in my Table located SQL Developer. The application is running fine in spring boot but it does not show any connectivity with my data in SQL developer. I have double checked my applications.properties file but no luck.

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username = DIP
spring.datasource.password = DIP
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
server.port = 8080
```

SQL DEVELOPER Connection Name

```
DIP@//localhost:1521/orcl
```

JDBC SYSTEM PATH IN POM.XML

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>21.4.0.0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/ojdbc8.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The password seems to be missing.

Comment: The `spring.datasource.url` also seems to be missing!

Comment: I forgot to include it here. I have updated the applications.file now.

Comment: Before you spend ton of time building this, we have a free oracle product for rest APIs, Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) oracle.com/rest